# "source" command inside a CSH scrip

Tags: csh

I wrote CSH script, include the following line:

> bash -c 'source $file; exec csh'

When running, I get the next error:

> bash: line 0: source: filename argument required source: usage: source

> filename [arguments]

Thanks too much!

Comment: When I run `bash -c 'echo name: -$file-'` I get `name: --` .

Comment: @kabanus , what did you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Lookup the difference between single quotes (') and double quotes (").

Since you are using single quotes, the variable is not expanded. I assume `$file` is a variable in the program where you are doing this.

Bash sees `source $file; exec csh` literally. It expands `$file`, but since that is not a variable to Bash, it expands to nothing. So the source command complains.

This works for me:

```
% set file='/tmp/bash_prog'
% bash -c "source $file; exec csh"
Hello from Bash!
%
```

Note how the last `%` is the prompt from the nested `csh`.